# How to correctly use ffmpeg to convert mkv to mp4 for use with Xbox One Edge browser?

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, fedora

I have a server with movies/shows added and converted automatically. Problem is that MOST of the files that start as mkv don't work on Xbox (Specifically played on edge browser, on my website). I don't really know much converting files so after trying every combination I could find on google I don't know what to do.

What can I do to get all of them working?

For starters as you can imagine it's pretty hard to search for anything containing the keyword `Xbox` and getting useful information. But, I found this post that seems to show supported file types. I don't know if edge has slightly different requirements or not:
https://www.ign.com/wikis/xbox-one/Supported_File_Types

One of the file types listed is `mpeg 4 h264 aac` which is what I've been trying to convert my movies to and still not playing.

A few commands I've tried:

```
  < /dev/null ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -vf format=yuv420p "${name}.mp4" -hide_banner;

  < /dev/null ffmpeg -i "$i" -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -c:a aac "${name}.mp4" -hide_banner;

  ffmpeg -i "$i" -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -c:a aac "${name}.mp4" -hide_banner;

  ffmpeg -i "$i" -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "${name}.mp4" -hide_banner;

  ffmpeg -i "$i" -codec copy "${name}.mp4";
```

And more...

Hopefully useful file info:
MKV:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1 /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/'Silicon Valley'/'Season 1'/S01E01*.mkv; 
codec_name=h264
codec_name=dts
```

Not working converted MP4:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1 /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/'Silicon Valley'/'Season 1'/S01E01*.mp4;                    codec_name=h264
codec_name=aac
codec_name=bin_data
```

Working MP4:

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1 /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/'Rick and Morty'/'Season 4'/*S04E03*.mp4;
codec_name=h264
codec_name=aac
```

The only difference I can tell so far is the bin-data codec. But I don't know why it's there on one and not the other.

Conversion log on non working mkv-mp4:

```
# for i in /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/'Silicon Valley'/'Season 1'/S01E01*.mkv;
>   do name=$(echo "${i//.mkv/}");
>   echo "$name";
>   < /dev/null ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -vf format=yuv420p "${name}.mp4" -hide_banner;
> done
/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Silicon Valley/Season 1/S01E01 - Minimum Viable Product Bluray-1080p
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Silicon Valley/Season 1/S01E01 - Minimum Viable Product Bluray-1080p.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.0
    creation_time   : 2015-03-13T05:58:12.000000Z
  Duration: 00:29:21.39, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10636 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 182.432000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0:1: start 182.432000, end 504.838000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:03:02.432
    Chapter #0:2: start 504.838000, end 913.329000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:08:24.838
    Chapter #0:3: start 913.329000, end 1236.110000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:15:13.329
    Chapter #0:4: start 1236.110000, end 1691.523000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:20:36.110
    Chapter #0:5: start 1691.523000, end 1761.387000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:28:11.523
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 1536 kb/s (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (dts (dca) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 0x561f95f4b5c0] Using a PCE to encode channel layout "5.1(side)"
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] profile High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] 264 - core 157 r2980 34c06d1 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=34 lookahead_threads=5 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Silicon Valley/Season 1/S01E01 - Minimum Viable Product Bluray-1080p.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 182.432000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0:1: start 182.432000, end 504.838000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:03:02.432
    Chapter #0:2: start 504.838000, end 913.329000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:08:24.838
    Chapter #0:3: start 913.329000, end 1236.110000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:15:13.329
    Chapter #0:4: start 1236.110000, end 1691.523000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:20:36.110
    Chapter #0:5: start 1691.523000, end 1761.387000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:28:11.523
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 13978 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 394 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame=   41 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.34 bitrate=   0.7kbits/s speed=4.68x frame=   58 fps= 58 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.05 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s speed=3.05x frame=   74 fps= 47 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.73
 --SNIPPED TOO LONG--
 bitrate=3985.6kbits/s speed=2.25xframe=42207 fps= 54 q=28.0 size=  856576kB time=00:29:21.10 bitrate=3984.5kbits/s speed=2.25x[matroska,webm @ 0x561f95e78580] File extends beyond end of segment.
frame=42224 fps= 54 q=28.0 size=  856832kB time=00:29:21.34 bitrate=3985.1kbits/s speed=2.25x[mp4 @ 0x561f95ea1040] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=42230 fps= 54 q=-1.0 Lsize=  863321kB time=00:29:21.38 bitrate=4015.2kbits/s speed=2.24x
video:776974kB audio:84842kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.174605%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] frame I:466   Avg QP:19.32  size:207180
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] frame P:11673 Avg QP:21.92  size: 35007
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] frame B:30091 Avg QP:23.52  size:  9652
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] consecutive B-frames:  2.8%  4.8%  5.2% 87.2%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] mb I  I16..4:  9.2% 89.1%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] mb P  I16..4:  2.7%  8.7%  0.5%  P16..4: 49.0%  9.5%  7.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:22.6%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  1.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 37.4%  1.6%  0.2%  direct: 2.4%  skip:57.2%  L0:44.7% L1:52.2% BI: 3.0%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] 8x8 transform intra:77.9% inter:91.0%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 56.8% 83.6% 51.8% inter: 9.8% 25.7% 2.8%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 41% 19% 10% 31%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20% 14% 35%  4%  5%  6%  5%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 16% 13%  5%  9%  9%  8%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 59% 16% 19%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:1.1% UV:0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] ref P L0: 58.5% 11.4% 22.6%  7.4%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] ref B L0: 86.8% 10.7%  2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] ref B L1: 95.2%  4.8%
[libx264 @ 0x561f95e9fbc0] kb/s:3613.70
[aac @ 0x561f95f4b5c0] Qavg: 284.855
```

I've thought I had this many times where I successfully get one video out of 60 to work, only to realize I was wrong. If there are any other ways I can get better logs let me know and I will.

Comment: Can you get [VLC on the Xbox One](https://www.windowscentral.com/vlc-windows-10-uwp-app-now-available-xbox-one)? VLC4 will have a media library in the UI when released too.

Comment: No, that won't work for my needs. It has to work for my website on edge as that's where most of my users use it. Installing VLC won't help them. If it were just me watching from my network that'd probably work.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like 5.1 audio although I would assume it supports that. Try `ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/uploads/Videos/TV/Silicon Valley/Season 1/S01E01 - Minimum Viable Product Bluray-1080p.mkv -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -t 120 -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

ffmpeg.exe -i "FILENAME.mkv" -target ntsc-vcd "FILENAME.MP4"

without the extras...

Comment: Have you got any to play with code you have used ?

Comment: I've gotten a couple to work with ffmpeg -n -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart  "${name}.mp4";  And some others with a simple rename.  But the current files I've been getting seem impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Converting mkv to mp4 with ffmpeg

https://gist.github.com/jamesmacwhite/58aebfe4a82bb8d645a797a1ba975132

"just copy the existing video and audio stream as is into a new container,
no funny business"

Please also read the comment(s)

--By: nickdagamer400 commented on Feb 19, 2018

(About the Batch (.bat) file in Windows)

for /R %%f IN (*.mkv) DO ffmpeg -i "%%f" -c copy "%%~nf.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend getting mediainfo to compare working/non-working files, so you can see the media details.

```
> mediainfo S01E08.Much\ More.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : S01E08.Much More.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 634 MiB
Duration                                 : 59 min 38 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 1 487 kb/s
Movie name                               : S01E08.Much More
Writing application                      : Lavf58.35.100
Comment                                  : -filter_complex [0:0]fps=fps=24000/1001[vOut];[0:1]loudnorm=linear=true:measured_I=-22.63:measured_tp=-3.77:measured_LRA=19.00:measured_thresh=-34.34[aOut] -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset medium -tune film -maxrate 8m -bufsize 2m -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -ar 48k -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng
LongDescription                          : No info

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 59 min 38 s
Bit rate                                 : 1 353 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.061
Stream size                              : 577 MiB (91%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 158
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:-1:-1 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.15 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=22 / lookahead_threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 59 min 38 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 6 channels
Channel layout                           : C L R Ls Rs LFE
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 54.6 MiB (9%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1

Text #1
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : Timed Text
Muxing mode                              : sbtl
Codec ID                                 : tx3g
Duration                                 : 58 min 38 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 44 b/s
Stream size                              : 19.1 KiB (0%)
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
Alternate group                          : 3

Text #2
ID                                       : 4
Format                                   : Timed Text
Muxing mode                              : sbtl
Codec ID                                 : tx3g
Duration                                 : 58 min 38 s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 56 b/s
Stream size                              : 24.0 KiB (0%)
Title                                    : SDH
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : No
Forced                                   : No
Alternate group                          : 3
```

Compare the codecs and profile used for working files.

Check the input file streams and map only the streams you really care about (Video/Audio (in your language)/Subtitles?)

```
> ffprobe S01E08.Much\ More.mp4 2>&1 |grep Stream
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1353 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 0 kb/s
```

Then build your ffmpeg command:

```
> ffmpeg -y -i "S01E08.Much More.mkv" \
  -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset medium -tune film -maxrate 8m -bufsize 2m -map 0:0 \
  -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -ar 48k -map 0:1 \
  -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -map 0:3 \
  "S01E08.Much More.mp4"
```

I'm not sure if you need -movflags or -faststart, they are used for streaming videos to start playing during transfer.